# Encoding in Qt model-view. QSqlModel QListView

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, unicode, model-view

I read unicode data from QSqlite database and the data appears not properly in QListView. Where should I set the encoding? model, view or globally in Qt?

The only one thing coming in my mind is to set a delegate to the view and convert the data in the delegate.

Comment: Well, you do a conversion from some encoding to QString somewhere, so do it there.

Comment: it would be good to provide little more - how do you read from sqlite db? if by using qsqldatabase, then there is almost no space for some adjustments - and I would guess that maybe strings are not really in unicode in db. If you read by your own codes then there are variants that strings (char * or so) are not properly converted into QString.

Comment: @yshurik Yes, I use QSqlDatabase (are there good reasons to use custom code in Qt?) The data is in Unicode (2Byte)  - each second byte is the same, if i copy and paste in an editor, and set encoding to unicode, I see proper text. But, how can QDataBase know, how to interprete the data? I've expected, there should be a possibility to set encoding. Is the Utf-8 a standard encoding probably?

Comment: @Velkan: If you write it as answer, I'll upvote and select it ;-)